# Latex add a name to an equation and display in a list of equations

Tags: latex

I have an equation:

```
\begin{equation}
    P(A \ | \ B) = \frac{P(A \ | \ B) \cdot P(A)}{P(B)} 
\end{equation}
```

I want to do 2 things. First, give it a name - "Bayes Theorem" and Secondly have it be displayed in a list of equations.

Comment: By give it a name, do you mean somthing like \label{my_eq}? Can you be more specific about what you want?

Comment: Similar to how you would caption a figure

Comment: Duplicate? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14317/list-of-equations-table-of-equations?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
\begin{figure}[h!t]
  \centering 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    $P(A \ | \ B) = \frac{P(A \ | \ B) \cdot P(A)}{P(B)} $
    \vspace*{0.5cm}
    \caption{this equation I want to talk about}
    \label{equ1}
  \end{subfigure}

  \vspace*{0.5cm}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    $P(A|B)=...$
    \vspace*{0.5cm}
    \caption{this other equation I want to talk about}
    \label{equ2}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

and here is a screenshot of what it does:

[image]